# Direction API service inside google maps for ios sdk

Tags: ios, google-maps, map-directions

Is there any API service available which can be called from inside Google Maps ios sdk just like **GMSAutocompleteFilter**?

```
GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity;

    [_placesClient autocompleteQuery:@"Sydney Oper"
                              bounds:nil
                              filter:filter
                            callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                              if (error != nil) {
                                NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                return;
                              }

                              for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {
                                NSLog(@"Result '%@' with placeID %@", result.attributedFullText.string, result.placeID);
                              }
                            }];
```

I know that using this `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&key=%@` I can implement and retrieve the response. But the problem is that this URL doesn't returns **overview_path** and **lat_lngs** which is only available in Latest [Google Maps Directions Service Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple).

Comment: The Directions API web service has an `overview_polyline` property in the HTTP response, you can use it to draw a polyline in your mapview. Also the `routes` property contain a list of `lat` and `lng`.

Comment: @ztan: I don't need `overview_polyline`. And I knew coordinates are being returned by the `routes`. But I need smooth directions which is available in `overview_path` and in `lat_lngs` under each `steps`.  Right now this feature integrated in latest google maps javascript API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference) updated on 04 Aug, 2015.